# Show that if $\phi$ is a cocycle then $\phi(f\cdot g)=\phi(f)+\phi(g)$ for

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is an exercise from Hatcher:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, $G$ an abelian group. Regarding a cochain $\phi\in C^1(X;G)$ as a function from the paths in $X$ to $G$, show that if $\phi$ is a cocycle then $\phi(f\cdot g)=\phi(f)+\phi(g)$

where $f\cdot g$ denotes the product path of two paths with $f(1)=g(0)$, i.e.

$$\newcommand{\del}{\partial}
(f\cdot g)(x)=\begin{cases}f(2x)&x\in[0,1/2]\\g(2x-1)&x\in[1/2,1]\end{cases}$$

I feel like this was meant to be a simple question, so I feel silly that I don't see how to solve it. Since $\phi$ is a cocycle, we have $0=\delta_2(\phi)=\phi\partial_2$ being the zero function. But I don't see why having $\partial_2$ involved should matter.

There must be something going on with the endpoints of $f$ and $g$, and some sort of manipulation like

$$\del_1(f\cdot g)=(f\cdot g)(1)-(f\cdot g)(0)=g(1)-f(0)=g(1)-g(0)+f(1)-f(0)=\del_1(g)+\del_1(f)$$

Can anybody help me see what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you construct a 2-simplex $\sigma$ such that its edges are respectively $f,f.g$ and $g$ so that $\partial_2\sigma=f-f.g+g$ ? Do not worry if $\sigma:\Delta^2\rightarrow X$ is very far from being injective.

Comment: @Roland I think I see now. So I can define a $2$-simplex $\sigma:[v_0,v_1,v_2]\to X$ say by defining $[v_0,v_1]\mapsto f$, $[v_0,v_2]\mapsto f\cdot g$, $[v_1,v_2]\mapsto g$, and map the interior somewhere arbitary, say $\text{int}(\sigma)\mapsto f(0)$. Then we get $0=\delta_2\phi(\sigma)=\phi\partial(\sigma)=\phi(f-f\cdot g+g)=\phi(f)-\phi(f\cdot g)+\phi(g)$, so $\phi(f\cdot g)=\phi(f)+\phi(g)$?

Comment: Well no, the map must be continuous, so the interior can't be arbitrary. Draw a picture and remember how the map $f.g$ is constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Roland put you onto the right track, but just so you have something to check against later (and for those who may come after):

Let $\sigma: \Delta^2 \to X$ be defined by first projecting $\Delta^2$ onto the edge $[v_0, v_2]$ (orthogonally, so that $v_1$ ends up mapping to the midpoint of $[v_0, v_2]$), and then mapping via $f\cdot g: [v_0, v_2] \to X$.  From this we have that:

$$\partial \sigma=\sigma|_{[v_1, v_2]}-\sigma |_{[v_0,v_2]}+\sigma |_{[v_0, v_1]}=g-f\cdot g +f$$

Hence as you observed we'd want in your comment:

$$0 =\delta\phi(\sigma) = \phi(\partial \sigma)=\phi(g-f\cdot g + g)=\phi(g) - \phi(f\cdot g) + \phi(f)$$

and therefore:

$$\phi(f\cdot g) = \phi(f)+\phi(g).$$